# Wanted: JRibbon tutorials

Tags: java

Is there anywhere I can find a tutorial on how to use the JRibbon of the [Flamingo](https://flamingo.dev.java.net/) project?

I downloaded and tried reading the test source files, but there is no explanation what so ever on how to use the various classes.

Comment: Have you considered asking Kirill? The one time I tried to use the ribbon (very early verison), I ran into all sorts of NPEs due to assumptions I made. He was very nice over email. Try going straight to the source

Comment: Thanks, will try to contact him...

Answer (score 3):

I used this tutorial to get started:

http://blog.frankel.ch/flamingo-tutorial

It must have been for an earlier version but after I had fixed the imports I was able to get it running and actually see a simple example of how to get this whole ribbon thing working.  It was also kind enough to point out how to use wrap regular icons and use them instead of the weird svg classes in the demo that comes with Flamingo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the expected answer but... I would get the [Slides for the JavaOne presentation on Flamingo ribbon](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1257) (this will give you a good overview of ribbon terminology and components hierarchy).

Then, I'd follow the advice - cough - given in the [Learn how to use](https://flamingo.dev.java.net/learn.html) section:

> Want to learn more? Browse the `org.jvnet.flamingo.ribbon` package.

I took a look and it seems to have more than decent javadoc. With this javadoc and the overview of the ribbon components and terminology, it seems possible to me to follow the samples provided in the test directory.

Maybe you'll be more lucky on the the project "users" mailing list though.

Comment: Funny thing... there is no mention about resize policies in the slide... which is the first thing you need to know to avoid getting an exception for adding the simplest bands... JavaDoc is by no means sufficient enough to provide a better explanation.. I might as well look at the source code examples.... which I did... and there are no comments about anything....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they constitute tutorials, but Kirill Grouchnikov has published a number of articles on the ribbon component at [Pushing Pixels](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/). This article looks like it's a reasonable starting point: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=283.

Comment: Unfortunately, the closest thing to having any sort of source code in Pushing Pixels is this post: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1475 I've looked all posts in the category "Flamingo" and all of them are similar to the one you provided, they basically contain a series of teaser screen shots and nothing more...